# How to convert office file like .doc .ppt and other on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, pdf, microsoft-office

Can anyone suggest me a command utility software for Ubuntu to convert all office files to pdf and it must be a free software.

Comment: This can be done using LibreOffice - please see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349542/command-libreoffice-headless-convert-to-pdf-test-docx-outdir-pdf-is-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349542/command-libreoffice-headless-convert-to-pdf-test-docx-outdir-pdf-is-not)

Comment: No please read question I mean to convert using command line.

Answer (score 8):

For true command-line conversion use command below:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf /path/to/original-file.doc
```

Comment: How to specific the save directly??

Comment: @HIMANSHUSINGH 2 lines: `cd /path/to/destination`, then as described in this answer.

Comment: Not possible.. Because I using php script to excute this and to use the cd command we need to make 2 commands excute with same terminal and with same data of terminal.